# How to convert Firestore Timestamp UTC to UTC+1 in React-Native using Moment?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I want to use MomentJs to convert Firestore Timestamp (which is by Default UTC) to UTC+1. How can I do that?

```
firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate()
```

P.S. I dont want to use the local/device's time.

Answer (score 2):

> Firestore Timestamp (which is by Default UTC)

There is no "default" really.  When you have a Timestamp object (or a [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or any other native date object from a modern operating system), the moment in time is **always** represented internally in UTC.

When you call `toDate()` on a timestamp, the resulting Date is still internally represented in UTC.

Don't be confused about the "default" string representation of a Date object.  It will appear in the local timezone where the computer's operation system is configured.  But internally, it's still UTC.

If you want to **format** the timestamp as a string for another timezone, you can certainly do that.  momentjs has an accompanying library [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) that can help you with that.  The momentjs library itself will not help you with timezones (other than the one provided by the local of the system where it is running), as it's generally understood that native timestamps are always UTC.

Comment: thanks! But how am I suppose to know what this UTC of Firstore timestamp timezone is? Because Moment Timezone requires the timezone in order to convert to another timezone

Comment: As I said, Firestore (and other date objects provided by modern operating systems) always use UTC.  Don't be fooled by what you see in the console, which is just formatted for the local timezone of your computer.

Comment: ok, then how can I know if the user has changed his timezone? This is important, I must know the exact timezone of a specific region, not the timezone of the device.

Comment: It doesn't matter. A point in time never changes, even if the configured timezone changes the way you format a date.

Comment: ok so can I just compare the current server timestamp to the one stored in a document? This way, a bad actor changing his timezone is avoided, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking now.  It seems like you have a different question than the one you originally asked.  In that case I suggest posting a new question to explain the new issue.